# Array in a Array SOAP V2 (WS-I Compliance Mode)

Tags: php, arrays, magento

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInvoiceCreate((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'itemsQty' => array('order_item_id' => 15, 'qty' => '1')));
```

$mainarray[];
$itemarray[];

I need multiple of this

```
array('order_item_id' => 15, 'qty' => '1')
```

Which means i need a array in a array.

```
foreach(statement){
array_push($itemarray, "order_item_id", echo $item->product_id;);
array_push($itemarray, "qty", echo $item->qty);
array_push($mainarray, $itemarray);
}
enter code here
```

Request Example SOAP V2 (WS-I Compliance Mode)
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.create.html

In fact i'm also not sure what do i replace the current

```
 array('order_item_id' => 15, 'qty' => '1')
```

with
 array($mainarray) ??

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way of using `array_push` your current `$itemarray` output will look something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'order_item_id'
    [1] => '200'
    [2] => 'qty'
    [3] => '2'
)
```

I would go back to basics and use something like to generate your multi dimensional array:

```
$itemarray[] = array("order_item_id" => $item->product_id, "qty" => $item->qty);
array_push($mainarray, $itemarray);
```

Edit:
Ok I reread your questions, ignore `$mainArray`.

`$result = $proxy->salesOrderInvoiceCreate((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'itemsQty' => $itemarray));`

That should work as with the other examples qty/itemsQty show it accepting multikey arrays.